# Visual Studio Code Auto Formatting not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-material2, autoformatting

Auto Format for ***Visual Studio Code*** (**not** Visual Studio) for Angular Material 2 elements is not working correctly.

Before Auto Format:

[image: 1]

After Auto Format:

[image]

(Note: I needed to use images because SO didn't like the formatting of my code...which proves my point!)

Please let me know if you need any more information to help debug...this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it was an issue.  It had to do with the following line:

```
<img class="ae-center-block" src="../../assets/tdgReports/images/{{selectedAssn.logo}}" style="height: 130px; padding: 20px;" />
```

When I took out the style in the img tag it formatted correctly.  Here is the working line:

```
<img class="ae-center-block" src="../../assets/tdgReports/images/{{selectedAssn.logo}}" />
```

Would love thoughts as to why this would cause an issue.